# No longer able to import BrowserAnimationsModule in Angular 4.2.3

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I have just upgraded to Angular 4.2.3, and am now getting an error on the following line in my AppModule file:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
```

The error is:

```
./~/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js
47:2-18 
"export 'AnimationBuilder' was not found in '@angular/animations'
./~/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js
78:2-18 
"export 'AnimationFactory' was not found in '@angular/animations'
./~/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js
612:15-31 
"export 'AnimationBuilder' was not found in '@angular/animations'
./~/@angular/animations/@angular/animations/browser.es5.js
39:35-45 
"export 'ɵPRE_STYLE' was not found in '@angular/animations'
./~/@angular/animations/@angular/animations/browser.es5.js
2275:29-39 
"export 'ɵPRE_STYLE' was not found in '@angular/animations'
./~/@angular/animations/@angular/animations/browser.es5.js
3808:97-107 
"export 'ɵPRE_STYLE' was not found in '@angular/animations'
```

This was working in Angular 4.1.2, and if I don't import this module everything works fine, I just don't get the animations.

Is this a bug in 4.2.3, or has there been a breaking change somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Angular CLI? I've had issues like this after upgrading but they were always fixed by nuking and recreating the node_modules directory structure in my project and/or global package.

Global package:

> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
>
> npm cache clean
>
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Local Project Package

> rm -rf node_modules dist
>   *(use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command >Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell)*
>
> npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
>
> npm install

Not sure why it happens, but the above process seems to fix it for me.